# MySQL no puede crear una Foreign Key

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mariadb

Estoy intentando crear unas tablas y cuando ejecuto el .sql me da error en una de las foreign key. No entiendo cual es el motivo del error pese a lo que he buscado. Os dejo el código abajo a ver si alguien es capaz de entenderlo. Muchas gracias!

```sql
CREATE TABLE clie (
    clie_nomb VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    clie_codi INT NOT NULL,
    clie_tipo VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    ...
    CONSTRAINT PK_clie PRIMARY KEY (clie_nomb, clie_tipo, clie_codi)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE kncl(
    clie_nomb VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    clie_codi INT NOT NULL,
    clie_tipo VARCHAR(1) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT FK_kncl
    FOREIGN KEY (clie_nomb, clie_codi, clie_tipo) 
    REFERENCES clie(clie_nomb, clie_codi, clie_tipo) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

ERROR:

```sh
Create table 'database'.'kncl' with foreign key 'FK_kncl' constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns.
```

Comment: Hola. Aquí **`REFERENCES clie_035(clie_nomb, clie_codi, clie_tipo)`** estás indicando como tabla de referencia a `clie_035`, muestra el `CREATE TABLE` de dicha tabla, no de `clie` o corrige si te has confundido. ¿Con quién quieres relacionar a `kncl` realmente, con `clie` o con `clie_035`?

Comment: @A.Cedano perdona, quería quitar el 035 de todos lados para que quede mas claro, pero se me ha olvidado editar esa parte. Lo cambio ahora

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *quitar el 035 de todos lados*? Necesitamos ver un ejemplo mínimo y verificable de lo que tienes realmente. En casos como estos es fundamental saber cómo se llaman las tablas y columnas **realmente** en cada caso.

Comment: @A.Cedano las tablas se llaman "x_035" no se si eso puede llegar a afectar, pero para subirlo aquí he decidido quitarlo. Creo que se ve mas claro. De todas formas solo cambia eso respecto a mi código.

Comment: El orden de los factores, altera el producto.. el orden de los campos en las claves es SUPER IMPORTANTE... no?

Comment: Pues eso, indicar los nombres reales de cada cosa, y observar el orden de las columnas en las claves compuestas, como te señala @gbianchi y ya lo tienes. Si defines así tu PK en la tabla padre: `PRIMARY KEY (clie_nomb, clie_tipo, clie_codi)` en la tabla hija debes poner el mismo orden: `FOREIGN KEY (clie_nomb, clie_tipo, clie_codi)` y también `REFERENCES clie(clie_nomb, clie_tipo, clie_codi)`.

Comment: @A.Cedano cierto, probaré a indicar la Primary Key de manera correcta. Hasta mañana no podré comprobar nada así que mañana me aseguro que vaya bien

Comment: @A.Cedano teníais razón. Esto me pasa por no fijarme bien. Muchas gracias a los dos